# in Pandas (python) how to add a column with groupby referenced by two column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a column to a Pandas GroupBy DataFrame. The  new column(E) is the sum of values of on column(C) with the same key(A,B).This key is formed by two other columns of the dataframe (A,B).

```
This is my Dataframe         

     A   B    C   D
0   foo one   1  15  
1   bar one   2  10  
2   foo two   4  20  
3   bar three 4  5   
4   foo two   5  6   
5   bar two   6  9   
6   foo one   7  8    
7   foo three 8  15  

what I want:
     A   B    C  D     E
0   foo one   1  15    8
1   bar one   2  10    2
2   foo two   4  20    9
3   bar three 4   5    4 
4   foo two   5  6     9
5   bar two   6  9     6
6   foo one   7  8     8
7   foo three 8 15     8
```

This is my code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
   ...:                           'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
   ...:                    'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
   ...:                           'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
   ...:                    'C' : ['1','2','4','4','5','6','7','8'],
   ...:                    'D' : ['15','10','20','5','6','9','8','15']})
```

What I have already try

```
df['E'] =df['C'].groupby(df['A,B']).transform('sum')
```

but doesn't works

Comment: `df['E'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].transform('sum')`

Comment: Thanks but with this code the result for column E was 'E' : ['17','2','45','4','45','6','17','8']} not what I need =/

Comment: I cannot replicate that issues: it produces your expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the aggregated sum of C by A and B and then merge the resultant dataframe with the original

```
>> df
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  1  15
1  bar    one  2  10
2  foo    two  4  20
3  bar  three  4   5
4  foo    two  5   6
5  bar    two  6   9
6  foo    one  7   8
7  foo  three  8  15

df2 = df.groupby(['A','B']).sum().drop(['D'], axis=1).rename(columns={'C':'E'})    

>> df2
           E
A   B       
bar one    2
    three  4
    two    6
foo one    8
    three  8
    two    9
```

The result can be obtained merging df and df2:

```
>> df.merge(df2.reset_index(), on=['A', 'B'], how='left')

     A      B  C   D  E
0  foo    one  1  15  8
1  bar    one  2  10  2
2  foo    two  4  20  9
3  bar  three  4   5  4
4  foo    two  5   6  9
5  bar    two  6   9  6
6  foo    one  7   8  8
7  foo  three  8  15  8
```

Comment: Thank @Mabel Villalba but your code  give the result for column E was 'E' : ['17','2','45','4','45','6','17','8']}     the same what happens with Cris' code  look like it is putting  one number by the side of the other not summing

Comment: What do you mean? It cannot give that result since the column E does not have these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the type of the column `C` you will see is `object`, because the values are strings, so you need to convert it to a numeric value, using [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), for example:

```
df['E'] = df.assign(C=pd.to_numeric(df.C)).groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform('sum')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     A      B  C   D  E
0  foo    one  1  15  8
1  bar    one  2  10  2
2  foo    two  3  20  8
3  bar  three  4   5  4
4  foo    two  5   6  8
5  bar    two  6   9  6
6  foo    one  7   8  8
7  foo  three  8  15  8
```